# Skipping iterator

Tags: c++, boost, stl, boost-iterators

I have a sequence of values that I'd like to pass to a function that takes a `(iterator begin, iterator end)` pair. However, I only want every second element in the original sequence to be processed.

Is there a nice way using Standard-Lib/Boost to create an iterator facade that will allow me to pass in the original sequence? I figured something simple like this would already be in the boost iterators or range libraries, but I didn't find anything.

Or am I missing another completely obvious way to do this? Of course, I know I always have the option of copying the values to another sequence, but that's not what I want to do.

**Edit:** I know about `filter_iterator`, but that filters on values - it doesn't change the way the iteration advances.

Comment: Ia asked a slightly different question on the same subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046747/c-stl-selective-iterator, bt I specifically requested no Boost, not very helpful then :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want [boost::adaptors::strided](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
struct TrueOnEven {
 template< typename T >
 bool operator()(const T&) { return mCount++ % 2 == 0; }
 TrueOnEven() : mCount(0) {}
 private:
  int mCount;
};

int main() {
 std::vector< int > tVec, tOtherVec;
 ...
 typedef boost::filter_iterator< TrueOnEven, int > TakeEvenFilterType;

 std::copy( 
  TakeEvenFilterType(tVec.begin(), tVec.end()),
  TakeEvenFilterType(tVec.end(), tVec.end()),
  std::back_inserter(tOtherVec));
}
```

To be honest, this is anything else than nice and intuitive. I wrote a simple "Enumerator" library including lazy integrated queries to avoid hotchpotch like the above. It allows you to write:

```
Query::From(tVec.begin(), tVec.end())
.Skip<2>()
.ToStlSequence(std::back_inserter(tOtherVec));
```

where `Skip<2>` basically instantiates a generalized "Filter" which skips every N-th (in this case every second) element.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that this is just a silly hack. It also makes many assumptions on how the internal algorithm uses the iterator and how `filter_iterator` uses the predicate. For example if `operator()` is evaluated twice for a given iterator, everything goes out of sync.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking it is, if the filter_iterator categorizes to anything else than `std::input_iterator` or `boost::SinglePass`. You should probably write a full-fledged `skipping_iterator` which is harder then it might seem...

Answer (score 2):

Here's Boost's [filter iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html). It is exactly what you want.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, read wrongly-ish. Here's a list of all iterator funkiness in Boost:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iterator/doc/#specialized-adaptors

I think a plain iterator_adaptor with an overloaded `operator++` that increments the underlying iterator value twice is all you need.

Comment: No, it is not. The filter iterator filters sequences with a predicate on the values - but I'd like to have a predicate on the iterator (if you wanna think of this as filtering at all). Basically, I just want to present `+=2` as `++` to my internal operator

Comment: the problem is that applying (in the implementation) operator++ twice can past end the container, without checking whether skipping element was already the end() iterator. Althogh I am having a for loop in mind for(skip_iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end() ; ++it){}

Comment: alfC: You would need to check if `it != end` inside the `operator++`, before the second call to the unlying iterator's `operator++`.

Comment: @rubenvb, but for that to be the case the iterator will have to know about the `end` internally. Would you have end as part of the iterator or would you pass it in the `next` (`++`) function?
In any case, that doesn't make any sense in the context of what an iterator is.