# Copy every other element using standard algorithms (downsampling)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, stl

say I have a `std::vector` with N elements. I would like to copy every n-th element of it to a new vector, or average up to that element then copy it (downsample the original vector). So I want to do this

```
std::vector<double> vec(N);
long n = 4;
std::vector<double> ds(N/n);
for(long i = 0; i < ds.size(); i+=n)
{
    ds[i] = vec[i*n];
}
```

or

```
for(long i = 0; i < ds.size(); i+=n)
{
    double tmp = 0;    
    for(long j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        tmp += vec[i*n+j];
    }
    ds[i] = tmp/static_cast<double>(n);
}
```

Is there a way to do this using the standard algorithms of C++? Like using std::copy with binary functions? I have billions of elements that I want to treat this way, and I want this to be as fast as possible.

PS: I would prefer not to use external libraries such as boost.

Comment: What is a "standard algorithm"?

Comment: @EdHeal `std::copy` etc.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5685983/335858

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist Why are you going to use standard algorithms when using loops makes the code easy to read?

Comment: Boost.Range has some nice adapters that would make this nicer. With the standard library alone, it's rather ugly.

Comment: @Vlad Because applying a fitting algorithm (emphasis on “fitting” here) is almost by definition easier to check for correctness.

Answer (score 4):

For readability, the loop would be a good idea, as pointed out by Vlad in the comments.  But if you really want to do someting like this, you could try:

```
int cnt=0,n=3; 
vector<int> u(v.size()/3); 
copy_if (v.begin(), v.end(), u.begin(), 
          [&cnt,&n] (int i)->bool {return ++cnt %n ==0; } );
```

If you want to average, it's getting worse as you'd have to similar tricks combining `transform()` with `copy_if()`.

**Edit:**
If you're looking for performance, you'd better stick to the loop, as stressed in the comments by *davidhigh*:  it will avoid the overhead of the call to the lambda function for each element.

If you're looking for an algorithm because you're doing this very often, you'd better write your own generic one.

Comment: You correctly gave the disclaimer. Just to confirm it: the above code could be approximately `n` times slower than the hand-written loop. Basically, it's O(N) where O(N/n) would be possible.

Comment: @davidhigh it will indeed be slower thant the loop, as the lambda function gets called for every element.

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own generic algorithms inspired from the design principles used in `<algorithm>`.

For the copy of every n elements:

```
template<class in_it, class out_it>
out_it copy_every_n( in_it b, in_it e, out_it r, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i=distance(b,e)/n; i--; advance (b,n)) 
        *r++ = *b;
    return r;
}
```

Example of use:

```
vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
vector<int> z(v.size()/3); 
copy_every_n(v.begin(), v.end(), z.begin(), 3);
```

For averaging the elements n by n, you can use:

```
template<class in_it, class out_it>
out_it average_every_n( in_it b, in_it e, out_it r, size_t n) {
    typename out_it::value_type tmp=0;
    for (size_t cnt=0; b!=e; b++)  {
        tmp+=*b;
        if (++cnt==n) {
            cnt=0; 
            *r++=tmp/n;
            tmp=0;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Example of use:

```
vector<int> w(v.size()/3); 
average_every_n(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin(), 3);
```

The advantage over your inital loops, is that this will work not only on vectors, but on any container providing the `begin()` and `end()` iterator.  And it avoids overheads that I pointed out in my other answer.

Comment: In fact this means to write own loops instead of using standard algorithms.:)

Comment: My secret hope is that they would be included in the next version of the standard ;-)

Comment: I don't think there's really anything exactly like this in the standard library. I agree with @Christophe that writing your own algorithm (and then using it) is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

If to use only standard library features and algorithms and if it is not allowed to use loops then the code can look the following way. Take into account that the code is based on the C++ 2014. If you need a code that will be compiled by a compiler that supports only C++ 2011 then you have to make some minor changes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 4;
    std::vector<double> src = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };
    size_t n = src.size() / N;
    std::vector<double> dst( n );

    std::copy_if( src.begin(), std::next( src.begin(), n * N ), dst.begin(),
                  [i = 0] ( auto ) mutable { return ( i = ( i + 1 ) % N ) == 0; } );

    for ( double x : dst ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    dst.assign( n, 0.0 );

    std::accumulate( src.begin(), std::next( src.begin(), n * N ), dst.begin(),
                     [i = 0] ( auto acc, auto x ) mutable
                     {
                         *acc += x; 
                         if ( ( i = ( i + 1 ) % N ) == 0 )  *acc++ /= N;
                         return acc;
                     } );

    for ( double x : dst ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
4.4 8.8 
2.75 7.15
```

This compound expression in the if condition

```
if ( ( i = ( i + 1 ) % N ) == 0 )  *acc++ /= N;
```

you can replace with more simpler one

```
if ( ++i % N == 0 )  *acc++ /= N;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have explicitly stated that you prefer not to use Boost, but any non-Boost solution would really be implementing exactly this sort of thing anyway, so I'll show you how I would do it in Boost. Ultimately, I think you're better off writing a simple loop.

Downsampling uses [`strided`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html)

```
boost::copy(
        input | strided(2),
        std::back_inserter(output));
```

Downsampling average additionally uses [`transformed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html), though this solution is non-generic and specifically relies upon `vector` being contiguous:

```
boost::copy(
        input | strided(2) | transformed([](auto& x){
                return std::accumulate(&x, &x + 2, 0) / 2.;
            }),
        std::back_inserter(output));
```

Of course that has issues if the input isn't an exact multiple of the stride length, so it'd probably be better to do something like:

```
auto downsample_avg = [](auto& input, int n){
    return input | strided(n) | transformed([&,n](auto& x){
        auto begin = &x;
        auto end = begin + std::min<size_t>(n, &input.back() - begin + 1);
        return std::accumulate(begin, end, 0.0) / (end - begin);
    });
};

boost::copy(
    downsample_avg(input, 2),
    std::back_inserter(output));
```

Comment: that's great mastery of boost !  Even if OP prefers not to use it

Answer (score 0):

how about this implemention?

```
#include <iterator>

template<typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
OutputIt DownSample(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first,
    typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type n) {
  while (first < last) {
    *(d_first++) = *first;
    std::advance(first, n);
  }
  return d_first;
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your code, and how it offers improvements over the other answers, posted some time ago.

Comment: It's esay to understand, using stdlib only and can be used with containers and raw array.