# Initialize a map with regex

Tags: c++, regex, dictionary, iteration, regex-group

I'm using a very nice and simple `std::vector<std::string>` initializer which takes an input string and regex. It's similar to a basic split, just it works with regex *Group1* matches:

```
static std::vector<std::string> match(const std::string& str, const std::regex& re) {
    return { std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator() };
}
```

Construction of a vector is done like below:

```
std::string input = "aaa(item0,param0);bbb(item1,param1);cc(item2,param2);";
std::vector<std::string> myVector = match(input, std::regex(R"(\(([^,]*),)"));
```

This results a vector containing `item0,item1,item2` extracted from an input string with regex:

[image]

Now my `match` function uses the first group results of the regex and (I believe) utilizes the `vector`'s intialization form of:

```
std::vector<std::string> myVector = { ... };
```

I'd like to create a similar `match` function to construct a `std::map<std::string,std::string>`. Map also has the above initializator:

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> myMap = { {...}, {...} };
```

My idea is to modify the regex to create more group results:

[image]

And I would like to modify the above `match` function to create a nice map for me with the modified regex (`\(([^,]*),([^)]*)`), resulting the same as this:

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> myMap = { {"item0", "param0"}, {"item1", "param "}, {"item2", "param2"}, };
```

### What I've tried?

```
static std::map<std::string, std::string> match(const std::string& str, const std::regex& re) {
    return { std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re, {1,2}), std::sregex_token_iterator() };
}
```

This one (in case of a vector) would put both *Group1* and *Group2* results into the vector. But it can not initialize a map.

**How can I still do that *easily* (Is it not possible with `sregex_token_iterator`)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what 'easily' does mean exactly, so here comes *simple* solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

static std::map<std::string, std::string> match(const std::string& str, const std::regex& re) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> retVal;
    auto token = std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re, {1,2});
    for (auto it=token++, jt=token; it != std::sregex_token_iterator(); ++it, jt = it++)
        retVal.emplace(*it,*jt);
    return retVal;
}

int main() {
    std::string input = "aaa(item0,param0);bbb(item1,param1);cc(item2,param2);";
    auto myVector = match(input, std::regex(R"(\(([^,]*),([^)]*))"));
    for (const auto& item : myVector)
        std::cout<<item.first<<'\t'<<item.second<<std::endl;
}
```

You can also could try to use [boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11) and homemade [generic algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817563/copy-every-other-element-using-standard-algorithms-downsampling).

Comment: Looks promising, is it possible somehow to skip the loop?

Comment: I believe that loop cannot be skipped, only be hidden under the hood. Why do you want to hide the loop?

Comment: You're welcome! I just don't know how to deal with advancing the iterators by two steps each time using something like `std::transform`. I think it is possible, but I'm almost sure that the solution will not differ qualitatively from that provided in links above.