# How can I get "address" of every Nth element of a vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

How can I get "address" of every Nth element of a vector without using "raw loop". std::copy_if seems to be a solution but I couldn't get the address of the element, I just could get the value.

Comment: How do you want to "get the address"?  Do you want to have a vector of the addresses?  Call a function with each of the addresses?  Have a function that produces each address?  Have an input iterator that produces the addresses?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [skipping iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685983/skipping-iterator)

Comment: vector of te addresses. I tried to std::transform but it returns all elements and I don't want to hold a counter and if statement in lambda.

Comment: Vectors are stored in contiguous memory ranges. Therefore if you have the address of the 1st element `&v[0]`, you can simply calculate the m-times.n-th element as `&v[0] + m * n * sizeof<T>` where `T` is the type of the vector elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a skipping iterator (also called strided iterator) with `std::for_each` (or similar algorithm). The standard library has no generic skipping iterators however.

In case you wish to implement a skipping iterator yourself, the idea is simple: Write a template that takes an iterator as an argument. This template is an iterator "adaptor". Delegate most of the iterator boilerplate to the adapted iterator, but implement a custom increment operator, which skips elements based on your criteria.

While iterator adaptors are reusable, and existing implementations are available, a simple loop can be much less work:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i += N)
```