# sequence of delimiters in function strtok

Tags: c++, delimiter, strtok

im trying to obtain tokens with function `strtok()` in C++. Is very simple when you use just 1 delimiter like:
`token = strtok(auxiliar,"[,]");`. This will cut `auxiliar` everytime the function finds `[`,`,`or`]`.

What I want is obtain tokens with a sequence of delimiters like: `[,]`
It is posible doing that with `strtok` function? I cannot find the way.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to pass in an array of delimiters, and have `strtok` tokenize on any one of them?

Comment: Actually, no, it appears you mean the opposite.  Do you want `strtok` to treat `[,]` as a **single** delimiter?

Comment: Just don't use C-strings and `strtok` in C++ as it just has too many pitfalls AND is destructive. Use `string` and `find`.

Comment: There is strtok_r if you want a re-entrant version of strtok.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `strtok` to treat `[,]` as a *single* token, this cannot be done.  `strtok` always treats whatever you pass in the delimiters string as individual, 1-character delimiters.

Beyond this, it's best to not use `strtok` in C++ anyway.  It is not re-entrant (eg, you can't nest calls), not type-safe, and very easy to use in a way that creates nasty bugs.

The simplest solution is to simply search withing a `std::string` for the particular delimiter you want, in a loop.  If you need more sophisticated functionality, there are tokenizers in the Boost library, and I've also posted code to do more comprehensive tokenizing using only the Standard Library, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046747/selective-iterator/3047106#3047106).

The code I've linked above also treats delimiters as single characters, but I think the code could be extended in the way you desire.

Comment: Oh shit, I think this is exactly what a I want. I will try it right now. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If this is really C++, you should use std::string and not C strings.

Here's an example that uses only the STL to split a `std::string` into a `std::vector`:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string str, std::string sep) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    do {
        i = str.find(sep, j);
        vec.push_back( str.substr(j, i-j) );
        j = i + sep.size();
    } while (i != str.npos);

    return vec;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = split("This[,]is[[,]your, string", "[,]");
    // vec is contains "This", "is[", "your, string"

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the new C++11 features, you can do it with regex and token iterators. For example:

```
regex reg("\[,\]");
const sregex_token_iterator end;
string aux(auxilar);
for(sregex_token_iterator iter(aux.begin(), aux.end(), reg); iter != end; ++iter) {
    cout << *iter << endl;
}
```

This example is from the Wrox book Professional C++.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use the boost library I think this will do what you want it to do - not totally sure though as your question is a little unclear

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::string data("[this],[is],[some],[weird],[fields],[data],[I],[want],[to],[split]");

   boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokens(data, boost::char_separator<char>("],["));

   std::vector<std::string> words(tokens.begin(), tokens.end());

   for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i=words.begin(),end=words.end(); i!=end; ++i)
   {
      std::cout << '\'' << *i << "'\n";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output

```
'this'
'is'
'some'
'weird'
'fields'
'data'
'I'
'want'
'to'
'split'
```

Comment: That treats any of the characters `[,]` as separators, not the sequence `[,]`.

Comment: I can't use external libraries anyway :(

Comment: @Urien - shame - boost is useful - and its just a header file for this :-)

Comment: @Mike I know - but it didnt create empty tokens which is what I thought the OP wanted - I havent looked yet but is there a  boost::XXXX_separator<std::string>("],[")) in boost?